# Reducing the number of ticklabels on x axis of the graph while keeping the curve with all the dataframe lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

At the end of the question, there is an example of a CSV file with data starting from records on April 17, 2023 to April 30, 2023 in the "open_local_data" column.

Well, note that that when trying to generate the graph points, they are reset to 1970 due to the formatting of the date and time column. However, if I convert the column to the date model provided by Pandas, the graph line is automatically changed to only a few daily points, but I would like to keep all unique points, only reducing the visual markings on the x-axis.

What should I do?

[image]

```python
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def chart():
    df_chart = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10.8, 10.8))
    ax.plot(df_chart['open_local_data'], df_chart['cumulative_back'], linestyle='-', linewidth=2, color='blue')

    def format_ytick(value, pos):
        if value.is_integer():
            return f'{int(value)}u'
        else:
            return f'{value:.2f}u'

    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_ytick))

    ax.set_title('Example', color='white')
    ax.set_xlabel('Data', color='white')
    ax.set_ylabel('Profit & Loss', color='white')

    locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

    ax.set_facecolor('black')
    ax.grid(color='orange', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('orange')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('orange')
    ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(2)
    ax.tick_params(colors='white')

    plt.savefig('example_chart.png', facecolor='black', dpi=500)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chart()
```

[image]

In my attempts, if I try to convert the column to Pandas' date format, the line and curve of the graph are not faithful to all 158 rows of the dataframe, the amount of points in the graph decreases and I don't want that to happen, I just want the legend to be changed for better visualization:

```python
df['open_local_data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['open_local_data'])
```

[image]

```
open_local_data,back,cumulative_back
2023-04-17 15:45:00,-1.0,-1.0
2023-04-17 16:00:00,0.68255,-0.31745
2023-04-17 16:00:00,-1.0,-1.31745
2023-04-18 15:45:00,0.7199500000000001,-0.5974999999999999
2023-04-18 15:45:00,0.21505,-0.38244999999999996
2023-04-18 15:45:00,1.0098,0.6273500000000001
2023-04-18 15:45:00,-1.0,-0.3726499999999999
2023-04-18 15:45:00,0.8976000000000001,0.5249500000000001
2023-04-18 16:00:00,-1.0,-0.47504999999999986
2023-04-18 16:00:00,1.7017,1.2266500000000002
2023-04-19 14:30:00,0.92565,2.1523000000000003
2023-04-19 15:45:00,1.0472,3.1995000000000005
2023-04-19 15:45:00,-1.0,2.1995000000000005
2023-04-19 15:45:00,2.9920000000000004,5.191500000000001
2023-04-19 16:00:00,-1.0,4.191500000000001
2023-04-19 16:00:00,-1.0,3.1915000000000013
2023-04-19 16:00:00,0.4114,3.6029000000000013
2023-04-19 16:00:00,-1.0,2.6029000000000013
2023-04-20 13:45:00,-1.0,1.6029000000000013
2023-04-20 14:30:00,-1.0,0.6029000000000013
2023-04-20 16:00:00,-1.0,-0.3970999999999987
2023-04-20 16:00:00,-1.0,-1.3970999999999987
2023-04-20 16:00:00,1.0659,-0.3311999999999986
2023-04-20 16:00:00,0.5236000000000001,0.19240000000000146
2023-04-20 16:00:00,0.7854000000000001,0.9778000000000016
2023-04-21 15:30:00,-1.0,-0.022199999999998443
2023-04-21 15:45:00,1.8326,1.8104000000000016
2023-04-21 16:00:00,-1.0,0.8104000000000016
2023-04-21 16:00:00,-1.0,-0.18959999999999844
2023-04-21 16:00:00,0.1589499999999999,-0.03064999999999854
2023-04-22 08:00:00,-1.0,-1.0306499999999985
2023-04-22 08:30:00,1.3277,0.2970500000000016
2023-04-22 09:00:00,1.3464,1.6434500000000016
2023-04-22 10:00:00,-1.0,0.6434500000000016
2023-04-22 10:30:00,-1.0,-0.35654999999999837
2023-04-22 11:00:00,1.4025,1.0459500000000017
2023-04-22 11:00:00,-1.0,0.04595000000000171
2023-04-22 11:00:00,-1.0,-0.9540499999999983
2023-04-22 11:00:00,-1.0,-1.9540499999999983
2023-04-22 11:00:00,-1.0,-2.9540499999999983
2023-04-22 11:00:00,-1.0,-3.9540499999999983
2023-04-22 11:00:00,0.3926999999999999,-3.5613499999999982
2023-04-22 11:00:00,-1.0,-4.561349999999998
2023-04-22 11:00:00,0.9537,-3.6076499999999982
2023-04-22 11:15:00,0.6732,-2.9344499999999982
2023-04-22 12:45:00,0.2244,-2.710049999999998
2023-04-22 13:00:00,-1.0,-3.710049999999998
2023-04-22 13:30:00,0.5797000000000001,-3.130349999999998
2023-04-22 15:45:00,-1.0,-4.130349999999998
2023-04-22 16:00:00,1.0846000000000002,-3.045749999999998
2023-04-22 16:00:00,0.27115,-2.774599999999998
2023-04-22 16:30:00,0.2057,-2.5688999999999984
2023-04-23 08:00:00,-1.0,-3.5688999999999984
2023-04-23 08:30:00,0.73865,-2.8302499999999986
2023-04-23 09:00:00,0.8789,-1.9513499999999986
2023-04-23 09:30:00,1.1033000000000002,-0.8480499999999984
2023-04-23 10:00:00,-1.0,-1.8480499999999984
2023-04-23 10:00:00,1.5521000000000005,-0.29594999999999794
2023-04-23 10:00:00,0.9163,0.6203500000000021
2023-04-23 10:00:00,-1.0,-0.37964999999999793
2023-04-23 10:00:00,-1.0,-1.379649999999998
2023-04-23 10:30:00,0.8134500000000001,-0.5661999999999979
2023-04-23 11:15:00,0.9537,0.38750000000000207
2023-04-23 12:30:00,-1.0,-0.6124999999999979
2023-04-23 12:30:00,-1.0,-1.612499999999998
2023-04-23 13:00:00,0.5516500000000001,-1.060849999999998
2023-04-23 13:00:00,-1.0,-2.060849999999998
2023-04-23 14:00:00,0.1402499999999999,-1.920599999999998
2023-04-23 15:45:00,1.6269000000000002,-0.29369999999999785
2023-04-23 16:00:00,-1.0,-1.2936999999999979
2023-04-24 14:00:00,-1.0,-2.2936999999999976
2023-04-24 14:00:00,-1.0,-3.2936999999999976
2023-04-24 15:45:00,1.4025,-1.8911999999999975
2023-04-24 16:00:00,1.1220000000000003,-0.7691999999999972
2023-04-24 16:15:00,0.4114,-0.35779999999999723
2023-04-25 14:30:00,-1.0,-1.3577999999999972
2023-04-25 14:30:00,-1.0,-2.3577999999999975
2023-04-25 15:30:00,1.2903,-1.0674999999999975
2023-04-25 15:45:00,0.92565,-0.14184999999999748
2023-04-25 15:45:00,0.7106,0.5687500000000025
2023-04-25 16:00:00,-1.0,-0.43124999999999747
2023-04-25 16:00:00,1.1781,0.7468500000000025
2023-04-25 16:00:00,-1.0,-0.25314999999999754
2023-04-25 16:00:00,-1.0,-1.2531499999999975
2023-04-25 17:00:00,-1.0,-2.2531499999999975
2023-04-26 14:30:00,-1.0,-3.2531499999999975
2023-04-26 14:30:00,0.3272500000000001,-2.9258999999999973
2023-04-26 15:00:00,0.5236000000000001,-2.402299999999997
2023-04-26 15:30:00,4.581500000000001,2.179200000000004
2023-04-26 15:30:00,-1.0,1.1792000000000038
2023-04-26 15:45:00,-1.0,0.1792000000000038
2023-04-26 15:45:00,1.0285000000000002,1.207700000000004
2023-04-26 16:00:00,0.90695,2.114650000000004
2023-04-26 16:00:00,0.9537,3.068350000000004
2023-04-26 16:00:00,0.66385,3.732200000000004
2023-04-26 17:00:00,-1.0,2.732200000000004
2023-04-26 17:00:00,-1.0,1.7322000000000042
2023-04-27 14:30:00,0.53295,2.265150000000004
2023-04-27 14:30:00,0.68255,2.947700000000004
2023-04-27 15:45:00,0.8228,3.770500000000004
2023-04-27 15:45:00,-1.0,2.770500000000004
2023-04-27 16:00:00,-1.0,1.7705000000000042
2023-04-27 16:15:00,-1.0,0.7705000000000042
2023-04-27 17:00:00,-1.0,-0.22949999999999582
2023-04-28 13:30:00,1.1407000000000005,0.9112000000000047
2023-04-28 15:30:00,-1.0,-0.08879999999999533
2023-04-28 15:45:00,1.6829999999999998,1.5942000000000045
2023-04-28 16:00:00,1.6643,3.258500000000004
2023-04-28 16:00:00,1.2342,4.492700000000005
2023-04-28 16:00:00,1.2342,5.726900000000004
2023-04-28 16:15:00,1.2903,7.017200000000004
2023-04-29 08:30:00,1.5334,8.550600000000005
2023-04-29 10:30:00,-1.0,7.550600000000005
2023-04-29 10:30:00,0.70125,8.251850000000005
2023-04-29 10:30:00,0.3739999999999999,8.625850000000005
2023-04-29 10:30:00,-1.0,7.625850000000005
2023-04-29 11:00:00,0.3552999999999999,7.981150000000005
2023-04-29 11:00:00,-1.0,6.981150000000005
2023-04-29 11:00:00,-1.0,5.981150000000005
2023-04-29 11:00:00,0.6077499999999999,6.588900000000005
2023-04-29 11:00:00,0.7293000000000001,7.318200000000005
2023-04-29 11:00:00,-1.0,6.318200000000005
2023-04-29 11:15:00,-1.0,5.318200000000005
2023-04-29 11:30:00,0.2431,5.5613000000000055
2023-04-29 12:00:00,0.2805000000000001,5.841800000000005
2023-04-29 13:00:00,-1.0,4.841800000000005
2023-04-29 13:30:00,1.3838,6.225600000000005
2023-04-29 13:30:00,0.1402499999999999,6.365850000000005
2023-04-29 13:30:00,0.86955,7.235400000000006
2023-04-29 15:45:00,1.309,8.544400000000005
2023-04-29 16:00:00,0.3926999999999999,8.937100000000004
2023-04-29 16:30:00,0.2805000000000001,9.217600000000004
2023-04-29 16:30:00,1.1033000000000002,10.320900000000005
2023-04-29 18:30:00,-1.0,9.320900000000005
2023-04-30 07:30:00,0.83215,10.153050000000006
2023-04-30 08:00:00,-1.0,9.153050000000006
2023-04-30 08:00:00,2.1972500000000004,11.350300000000006
2023-04-30 09:00:00,-1.0,10.350300000000006
2023-04-30 09:30:00,1.0846000000000002,11.434900000000006
2023-04-30 10:00:00,1.4399000000000002,12.874800000000006
2023-04-30 10:00:00,-1.0,11.874800000000006
2023-04-30 10:00:00,0.7480000000000001,12.622800000000005
2023-04-30 10:00:00,0.2618,12.884600000000004
2023-04-30 10:00:00,0.2431,13.127700000000004
2023-04-30 10:00:00,-1.0,12.127700000000004
2023-04-30 10:00:00,-1.0,11.127700000000004
2023-04-30 10:00:00,1.0472,12.174900000000004
2023-04-30 10:30:00,0.1028500000000001,12.277750000000005
2023-04-30 11:15:00,0.6358,12.913550000000004
2023-04-30 12:05:00,-1.0,11.913550000000004
2023-04-30 12:30:00,0.5423000000000001,12.455850000000005
2023-04-30 13:00:00,0.3459500000000001,12.801800000000005
2023-04-30 14:00:00,0.21505,13.016850000000005
2023-04-30 15:45:00,0.2992000000000001,13.316050000000006
2023-04-30 15:45:00,-1.0,12.316050000000006
2023-04-30 16:00:00,0.66385,12.979900000000006
2023-04-30 16:30:00,0.2244,13.204300000000005
2023-04-30 18:10:00,0.7854000000000001,13.989700000000006
```

Comment: In the first case (object), matplotlib gives even the 15 mins (15:45 and 16:00) same horizontal space as 16:00 and next day 15:45. When you change it to pandas datetime, the time of 15 mins is very small, while the next day is almost 24 hrs, so the plot looks different. The points are all there, just either very close or very far. The one with datetime is actually correct, as this has time correctly spaced out

Comment: @Redox Currently the graph is correct in relation to the line and curve generated, but the caption of the X axis is wrong because months of 1970 were generated, which do not match reality, this is the question that I could not understand what and how do to fit without changing the current line and curve.

Comment: Actually it is not correctly spaced on x-axis as row 1 and row 2 are equally spaced as 3 & 4 even though the first one is 15 mins away, while the second one is (24 hrs-15 mins) away. The locator/formatter you are using later is giving dates from Jan 1st through Apr 1st of 1970. The reason is there are 90 unique dates (`df_chart.open_local_data.nunique()`) and each is taken as the next date starting from Jan 1st 1970, which is the first date in matplotlib

Comment: Are you looking to keep the graph you with date column as object, but only change the ticklabels? I guess above explanation was more on why you are seeing what you are seeing :-)

Comment: @Redox If I directly add the ```open_local_data``` column as the x axis, 158 ticklabels will appear, this makes the graph very difficult to understand, so I would like to generate a graph with a smaller number of ticklabels but the line and curve of the graph faithful to the 158 lines dataframe's cumulative sum column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you want each unique date and time entry to be equally spaced. To do this, you will need to keep the dates as object (as in the code), use the locator and formatter. Post that, replace the x-ticklables with new dates in the format you want. This will overwrite the dates show what you need. Add below code right after the `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)` line... Note this will give a warning as you are using formatter and then overwriting, but should plot what you need.

```
    ## Get the labels plotted
    labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
    import pandas
    ## Get a list of dates (count of labels) between min and max
    mydates = pandas.date_range(df_chart.open_local_data.min(),df_chart.open_local_data.max(),periods=len(labels))
    ## Convert to text - you can change the way you want to display
    mydates=mydates.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    ax.set_xticklabels(mydates)  ## Overwrite labels
```

**Plot**

[image]